# How do I run an external javascript function in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html

I can run Javascript in-page, thus:

`Javascript.html`:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hello <span id="mySpan"> World! </span>
    </body>
    <script>
        function worldInSpanish() {
            return "Mundo!";
        }
        document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML = worldInSpanish();
    </script>
</html>
```

> Hello Mundo!

But when I try to run it from an external file, it doesn't work.

`javascript.js`:

```
function worldInSpanish() {
    return "Mundo!";
}
```

`External_javascript.html`:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hello <span id="mySpan"> World! </span>
    </body>
    <script src="javascript.js">
        document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML = worldInSpanish();
    </script>
</html>
```

Doesn't change the text:

> Hello World!

What am I doing wrong? I'm guessing that I need to do something more to "import" the function into the HTML page or "export" it from the Javascript file.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: JavaScript within a `<script>` element which has a `src` attribute set is not executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: If the "src" attribute is present, the  element must be empty.**

The `<script>` tag is used to define a client-side script (JavaScript).

The `<script>` element either contains scripting statements, or it points to an external script file through the `src` attribute.

The `src` attribute specifies the URL of an external script file.

If you want to run the same JavaScript on several pages in a web site, you should create an external JavaScript file, instead of writing the same script over and over again. Save the script file with a `.js` extension, and then refer to it using the `src` attribute in the `<script>` tag.

Note: The external script file cannot contain the `<script>` tag.

Note: Point to the external script file exactly where you would have written the script.

**So either you have to import js file another script tag like**

```
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

or **You can import such function on that script tag and remove src attribute** that you have done firstly. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot. JavaScript files can simply contain functions to import, or they can also use functions. And they get executed in the web page at the point that they are found in the web page.

Answer (score 4):

You need to import your JavaScript file in a separate code tag.
And your script elements should be either in body, or header.

```
<html>
  <body>
    Hello <span id="mySpan"> World! </span>

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML = worldInSpanish();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script tags belong within the `<body>` or `<head>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use separate `<script>` tags for your external file and inline JavaScript.

And as @ShammelLee said, within your `<head>` or `<body>` tag.

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hello <span id="mySpan"> World! </span>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML = worldInSpanish();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem. you are using same tag for attaching the external, and calling the function, do it in separate tags

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hello <span id="mySpan"> World! </span>
    </body>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML = worldInSpanish();
    </script>
</html>
```